# Sublime Text 2 showing weird space bubbles. How do I turn this off?

Tags: sublimetext2

I pressed something accidentally on my keyboard and now I have all these annoying whitespace bubbles showing up. Does anyone know how to turn this off??

Comment: I can't add a photo b/c I'm new, but basically what I am seeing is just all of my spaces highlighted by a bubble

Comment: How to use your text editor is not the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set this in your preferences:

```
    "draw_white_space": "none",
```